# C++: Optimized list

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization, stl

Some intensive profiling of my code revealed that a it spends a lot of time allocating space for vectors.
For Most of these vectors the size is known in advance so I call `reserve()` to pre-allocate the space.
For most of these vectors, the size is almost always very small - like 4 or 5 elements but on rare occasions it can be pretty large.
One additional optimization I thought about is to create my own container `OptimizedList<T,N>` . An instance of this object contains in itself N instances of T as a plain array and if the user tries to add more than N items, it starts using dynamic allocation for the extra items.

Is there a known implementation of this?

Comment: have you tried replacing vector with [`deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)? You can also reserve the known size in advance, if you know it, in the case of vector

Comment: Why not `std::deque` ?

Comment: How are you using your vectors? Try to reuse the same vector from outside a loop instead of recreating the vector each iteration, for example. If the maximum size is small and known at compile-tile, use `std::array`

Comment: There is a constructor for `std::vector` that takes the initial number of elements.

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov why the suggestion of deque? Also its space cannot be reserved.

Comment: @NeilKirk, the reserve part of the answer is for a possible vector optimization (or with a constructor, as others suggest). Deque doesn't need contiguous memory, and hence might not need to reserve huge chunks as might be the case in your problem

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov My reading of the question is it's a problem of speed and not space. Time to allocate a chunk of memory doesn't depend much on its size. 1 large chunk is faster than several small chunks.

Comment: @NeilKirk i think the bottleneck is not reallocate itself, but copy/destroy part of it. So most good optimisation in this case is remove vector reallocations(and following object copying) at all. See my answer for details.

Comment: @PSIAlt Possibly but he says he is using reserve most of the time to the maximum size, which removes this problem.

Comment: I think that if you spend a lot of time on allocations the only effective solution is to avoid allocations reusing objects. A manager class will help a lot here, borrowing the ownership of a vector in a pool to everyone who need it and taking the ownership back when done.

Comment: @NeilKirk I don't think one can say for sure without a benchmark. Btw, see [gotw054](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm). P.S. what about fragmentation?

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov Calls to new are expensive, so the less the better. I don't have any evidence to hand. Fragmentation is an issue with giant vectors but I would expect that to result in memory failures. Use of vector with reserve reduces fragmentation.

Comment: Ultimately I believe slowness comes from shoosh's inefficient use of vectors so OP needs to provide more information about how the used. See my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about Qt's [stack based variable length array](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvarlengtharray.html)?

Looks like the perfect match for your use case, mostly small arrays, which will be allocated on the stack (the fastest allocation, just a pair of add / sub instructions on a pointer)
for small arrays, and on the heap for large ones.

It does however waste space.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using `std::vector` with a custom allocator optimized for 4-5 elements (pulling those from a pool) as the simplest and most viable solution. This is also the only solution that I'd expect to actually give a net benefit.

Using a `std::deque` probably does not help, although it may seem that way from a textbook point of view. It might actually hurt. Deques reduce the overhead of copying data from O(n) to O(1), but they are not magically allocation-free. On the contrary, they may cause a lot more allocations than using a vector would.
Deques are usually implemented either as vector of vectors or as circular buffer. In the latter case, you have exactly the same reallocation overhead as with using `std::vector` *except you can't mitigate it by calling `reserve()`*, and in the former case you have two allocations where you would otherwise only have one.

Embedding the first few objects directly into your custom vector class or into an on-stack vararray as in Bgie's answer is very tempting, and this would indeed be a great solution for not too many not too large vectors.
However, since you are having a performance problem from creating those vectors, one can conclude that you are not using just 5 or 10 vectors, but *many* of them (otherwise it wouldn't really matter, it wouldn't be measurable!).  Which means putting data on the stack would likely cause an eventual stack overflow.
This *may* however be a good solution if all your vectors are heap-allocated anyway. There is no real difference whether you allocate a few hundred bytes more when allocating the container itself, and there is no risk overflowing the stack. So in that case, you'd effectively save one allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Because most of your containers are small and rare containers get many elements, i'd prefer `std::deque`. This can help you to avoid unnecessary reallocations at low price. It does not have the `reserve()` method, but since most containers are small, i think its ok.

**More important**, you should check your object type, which is contained in those containers. I think the bottleneck is not reallocate itself, but copy/destroy part of it. I suspect that "container's values" copy constructors and/or destructors are "heavy" enough. Its very time-consuming to copy N elements and then destroy old N elements when constructors/destructors are  too complicated.

As last optimization, i'd suggest to use a memory pool/allocator to reduce underlying malloc/realloc/free calls.

Comment: I disagree that deque is faster than properly reserved vector in general.

Comment: @NeilKirk we don't know how he do the reserve and how precisely it is. Probably he reserve 100 and then sometimes insert 100k. Maintaining efficient usage of `vector` is more complicated in my opinion(and can be discussed for a long topic). So probably OP can solve the problem with just switching container type.

Comment: There is too many assumptions and possibles. If he is reserving vector correctly, then switching to deque would cause many more allocations

Comment: @NeilKirk yes, more allocations, but less "reallocations". By reallocation i mean allocation and following "copy+destroy" calls.

Comment: @NeilKirk its his assumption that "most time is consumed by allocation". I think its wrong path and suggest my own.